# I can't read a number in a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to open a file, reads the strings representing numbers of type `int`, and put them in order but it wont read `int n6 = inputStream.nextInt( );`. Once I take away the `int n6` code, it works.
This is the code in main, I know the 6th one isn't in the correct place, this is to show you that it won't work.  I'm also using NetBeans if that helps.

the numbers are: `5, -3, 3, 8, 4, 0`

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

Scanner inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("stuff.txt"));
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    int n1 = inputStream.nextInt( );
    int n2 = inputStream.nextInt( );
    int n3 = inputStream.nextInt( );
    int n4 = inputStream.nextInt( );
    int n5 = inputStream.nextInt( );
    int n6 = inputStream.nextInt( );

    inputStream.nextLine();
    String line = inputStream.nextLine();

    System.out.println(n2);
    System.out.println(n1);
    System.out.println(n3);
    System.out.println(n5);
    System.out.println(n4);
    System.out.println(n6);

    inputStream.close();
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `nextLine` calls

Comment: Well, that makes a nice change ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using nextLine() and using this code snippet:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("ContainsInts.txt"));
int [] ContainsInts = new int [100];
int i = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
     ContainsInts[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

I hope this helps, I had this same problem a few weeks ago lol

Comment: Using an `ArrayList` instead of an array is safer, as it grows when you add more elements.  If your file contained more than 100 integers, this code would fail.